# Двумерный массив ArrayList

Tags: java

Использовал для своего кода стандартный массив по типу:

```
String[][] HabitList = new String[3][3];
```

Но потом появилась необходимость менять величину массива во время исполнения кода, но обычный массив нельзя увеличивать на сколько мне известно, а массив `ArrayList` не может быть двумерным, на сколько мне известно.

Каким образом можно выйти из сложившейся ситуации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему не может? Может

```
List<List<Integer>> habitList = new ArrayList<>();
habitList.add(new ArrayList<>());
habitList.add(new ArrayList<>());
habitList.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Эм, не очень понял, это создаётся массив внутри другого массива?

Comment: Это создаётся список списков, в который добавляются три списка целых чисел.

Comment: А могли бы дать пример записи данных в такой массив? А то я впервые вижу такое и не очень понимаю как оно работает)

Comment: `habitList.get(0).add(42)` Достаточно почитать документацию к [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) чтобы все вопросы снялись.

Comment: @Andrew [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).